# Skype API System.IndexOutOfRangeException C#

Tags: c#, arrays, api, cmd, skype

So there's a program i saw, coded in c#. I keep getting errors on it. System.IndexOutOfRangeException is the main one, its happening at "args[0]". This is the code:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Skype4COMUserProfile
    {
        class Program
        {
            private static SKYPE4COMLib.Skype skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();

            [STAThread]
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                if (!skype.Client.IsRunning)
                {
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
                    skype.Client.OpenUserInfoDialog(args[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I will be very grateful if someone could tell me how to fix this. thank you in advance!

Comment: Looks like args is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that will fail if `args` is empty. Presumably you're meant to start the program by specifying a user name, or something like that.

You could always check for that:

```
if (args.Length == 0)
{
    // Show an error dialog here
    return;
}
```